# Python: Is it possible to make 'print' flush by default?

Tags: python, printing, stdout, default, flush

The `print` function in Python 3 may receive a boolean value to whether flush immediately or not:

```py
print("foobar", flush=True)
```

I wish to have the `print` function flush by default for everything it prints, is it possible? Work-around, ad-hoc settings, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this does looks like task for [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), but I am not sure if it would work in this case, so can you please try following: add at begin of your file

```
import functools
print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)
```

and test if it does what you want?

Answer (score 5):

You can run Python in unbuffered mode with:

```
python -u
```

Or set the environment variable

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
```

Comment: this is a bit relying on the command line and not committed to git through it's good with a bash file to go with